# dpdk mbuf and mempool messages with high log level

Tags: c, linux, dpdk

Is there any clue, how to enable all mempool,mbuf debugs in DPDK. i am using DPDK 2.2.0., i found some [answers](http://dpdk.org/ml/archives/dev/2013-July/000260.html) which is not much helpful on this version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could check the DPDK source code, rte_log.h, to check the definition of RTE_LOG.

You could

```
1) define RTE_LOG_LEVEL in Makefile, or
2) define RTE_LOG_LEVEL in rte_log.h before RTE_LOG, e.g. 
      #define RTE_LOG_LEVEL   8
```

then all low level debug information will be log file, You can also redefine this macro as print to console if you like.

in DPDK, the log is also controlled by **rte_logs.type**, you need check the value, each module is a bit, please see rte_log.h RTE_LOGTYPE_XXX.

if the above doesn't work, try the following

```
#define RTE_LOG_LEVEL   8
#define RTE_LOG(l, t, ...)                  \
    (void)((RTE_LOG_ ## l <= RTE_LOG_LEVEL) ?       \
     rte_log(RTE_LOG_ ## l,                 \
         RTE_LOGTYPE_ ## t, # t ": " __VA_ARGS__) : \
 0)
```

in eal_common_log.c

```
int rte_vlog(uint32_t level, uint32_t logtype, const char *format, va_list ap)
{
    ret = printf(format, ap);
    return ret;
}
```

recompile the whole DPDK and check whether there are log produced. If this work, then chnage *rte_vlog* back, just check the output file name and global variable mentioned above.

Comment: Hi Kevin, i tried to change "build/include/rte_config.h" , as well as Makefile of my app($SDK/examples/kni/Makefile) but i dont find any changes in the output logs.

Comment: @SakthivelThandabani I changed the answer, please check whether the log works and then tune it.

Comment: by default high log-level (8) is enabled, in example apps. So for checking purpose i downgrade it to 1(as per your code). but still i am getting  all logs. i just want to know where should i made change for LOG_LEVEL_ERR, so that i can get error condition logs only.. Actually i suspect some mbuf allocation fails while running my app, i just want to print logs for those.

Comment: I was thought that you can not print the log. If you suspect there was something wrong, you can just find the log string in source code and check what's the log level in code. If it is ERROR level, then system do running error. I used DPDK from since old release (1.5) and now upgraded to 2.1 and didn't find there are wrong in DPDK, there was some error which normally application not correctly used. I am not use 2.2 yet.

Comment: "just find the log string in source code and check what's the log level in code" , this might be good solution for my case. Thaks for the inputs. I didn't mean, there is some error in DPDK, i just want to know where my exactly fails, so thought getting mbuf/mempool debugs will help.